# Is it possible to have tables in Yammer notes?

Tags: yammer

Is it possible to have a table (HTML table, essentially) in a Yammer note? Seems the basic HTML editing functionality is there, but tables are missing.

Answer (score 1):

Tables aren't supported out of the box with Yammer notes.

Comment: "Out of the box" implies there's a way to add tables?

Comment: No, there isn't any way to do this at all in Yammer Notes.